# I cannot get jQuery to work in wordpress

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress

Tried many different techniques to get jquery working in my custom wordpress theme but still haven't got anywhere.

I've included two different methods that I've tried below near the end of the code, with one commented out here.

Can anyone see why this code might not be working?

PHP:

```
<?php

function wpb_custom_new_menu() {
    register_nav_menu('my-custom-menu',__( 'My Custom Menu' ));
}

add_action( 'init', 'wpb_custom_new_menu' );

function enqueue_stylesheets() {
    wp_enqueue_style('style', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/css/style.css');
    wp_enqueue_style('fonts', 'https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:400,600,700|Raleway:400,500,600,700');
    wp_enqueue_style( 'fontAwesome', 'https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css' );
}

/*function wp_enqeue_scripts() {
    wp_register_script('navbarScroll', home_url() . '/js/navbarScroll.js', array( 'jquery' ));
    wp_enqueue_script('navbarScroll');
    //wp_enqueue_script( 'bootstrap-js', 'https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js', array('jquery'), '3.3.4', true );
}*/

function navbar_script() {
    wp_register_script( 'jquery.navbarScroll', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/jquery.navbarScroll.js', array( 'jquery' ) );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery.navbarScroll' );
}

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_stylesheets', 'enqueue_scripts', 'navbar_script');
```

My Test JS (I've used both $ and jquery):

```
jquery(document).ready(function() {

jquery('#jQueryTest').html('jQuery is Working');

jQuery('nav').hover(function() {
    $(this).css('display', 'none');
})

/*var a = $('nav').offset().top;

$(document).scroll(function() {
    if ($(this).scrollTop() > a)
    {   
       $(this).removeClass('nav');
       $(this).addClass('nav-scrolled');
    } else {
       $(this).removeClass('nav-scrolled');
    }
});*/

});
```

Comment: Do you have some errors displaying on console?

Comment: what exactly is your problem?

Comment: I'm getting an error message in the console saying 'jquery is not defined' in my js file. I've updated the question to include my js as well

Comment: Try installing this plugin, https://wordpress.org/plugins/use-google-libraries/

Answer (score 0):

Well it seems that you have too many parameters in your `add_action` function.

The `add_action` should have only 4 arguments as follows:

```
add_action( string $tag, callable $function_to_add, int $priority = 10, int $accepted_args = 1 )
```

See [WordPress documentation](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/add_action/) for more information.

That's what should be working just fine:

```
function enqueueScript() {

wp_enqueue_style('style', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/css/style.css');
wp_enqueue_style('fonts', 'https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:400,600,700|Raleway:400,500,600,700');
wp_enqueue_style( 'fontAwesome', 'https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css' );


wp_enqueue_script( 'bootstrap-js', 'https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js', array('jquery'), '3.3.4', true );
wp_register_script('navbarScroll', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/navbarScroll.js', array( 'jquery' ), '', true );
wp_enqueue_script('navbarScroll');
wp_register_script( 'jquery.navbarScroll', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/jquery.navbarScroll.js', array( 'jquery' ), '', true );
wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery.navbarScroll' );
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueueScript' );
```

Note that it is not necessary to enqueue style and script separately. One method can do both by using `wp_enqueue_scripts`.

If you really want to separate your style and script in different function, you should call `add_action` this way:

```
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts','wp_enqueue_scripts');
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts','enqueue_stylesheets');
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts','enqueue_scripts');
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts','navbar_script');
```

If you want to load jQuery, add it to your function:

```
wp_enqueue_script('jquery', 'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js', array(), null, true);
```

Comment: What is the error you are getting? 404 for jquery only?

Comment: Updated answer how to include jquery if that's what you mean.

Comment: @HyderB. in wordpress it is already jquery loaded with the bundle. We don't have to use the link for it. Look into my answer which will load jquery.

Comment: Yes, already loaded by default unless it has been deregistered somewhere else. Your answer is good if the user want to load the jquery version that comes bundled with jquery. Or you specify the specific version of jQuery like I have done.

Comment: I'm still having no success with this

Answer (score 0):

Its easy if you can have a code like this to solve correctly and without confusiong. You have forgotten to pass add_action for your scripts.

```
function wpb_custom_new_menu() {
    register_nav_menu('my-custom-menu',__( 'My Custom Menu' ));
}

add_action( 'init', 'wpb_custom_new_menu' );

function enqueue_stylesheets() {
    //For registering Styles
    wp_enqueue_style('style', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/css/style.css');
    wp_enqueue_style('fonts', 'https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:400,600,700|Raleway:400,500,600,700');
    wp_enqueue_style( 'fontAwesome', 'https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css' );

    //For registering Scripts files
    wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery');
    wp_enqueue_script( 'bootstrap-js', 'https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js', array('jquery'), '3.3.4', true );
    wp_register_script('navbarScroll', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/navbarScroll.js', array( 'jquery' ), '', true );
    wp_enqueue_script('navbarScroll');
    wp_register_script( 'jquery.navbarScroll', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/jquery.navbarScroll.js', array( 'jquery' ), '', true );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'jquery.navbarScroll' );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_stylesheets' );
```

Hope this works for you.

THanks

Comment: If you want jquery to load i will updated the answer look in to it.